# rigid body keyframe animation not working in blender game

Tags: blender

I used a cube with rigid body physics and set keyframes.

i made another object with 'collision' logic brick to detect that cube as it touches this object.

i added 'always' logic brick to the cube to animate it.

i also set the start frame and end frame.

it animates fine in blender game when i press 'p'

but when i record the animation its not animating.

what is the problem? i am finding it hard to figure out.
i am a new to blender.

anyone has a solution to this ?

Comment: this is a question we can't answer with what you mentioned so far.
How did you record the Animation? As there are hundreds of possible problems, even bugs, it is necessary to describe every step AND Sharing a Blendfile. If it is just a test.blend with a cube sharing does not hurt right?

Sometimes it is a bug, sometimes the method is not right, sometimes in a version a feature is not supported. Writing down every possibility which maybe perhaps could be the cause of a problem is to much work and you would have to read that long list too.
Best wishes,Gerd

Comment: i checked the 'record animation' option and then pressed the p key. i noticed that any object with the 'rigid' physics setting is not animating.